# Dropbox upgrading with huge files

Tags: dropbox

I am using Dropbox on ubuntu (16.04) and noticed that the Dropbox folder contains a folder `.dropbox.cache` which in turn contains a folder `temp_dirs` containing 155(!) folders named `3ac3119f-3990-13c1-d09f-3b5d2d124a92` and the like, 75 of which contain files all named `dropbox-upgrade-81.4.195.tar.gz` and each is 98.1 MB big.

The total size of these files is thus about 7.5 GB.

The Dropbox menu says `Upgrading Dropbox...` and I understand that these files *might* be related to the upgrade, but the hard drive does not have enough disk space to fill all 155 folders with 100 MB files and I find it strange that 7.5 GB worth of upgrade files would be needed to upgrade a 339 KB package...

Does anyone have an idea what is going on here?

Comment: If yoou go to your account by selecting Launch Dropbox Website from the icon on the top bar then clcik on the round icon in the top right hand corner (which might be your photo if you have selected that option) the dropdown menu will tell you what you used against your total available. There are many system files and if these are appearing in your home folder, you can hide them by clicking Ctrl-H. They don't contribute to your allowed total.

Comment: @Graham OP's issue seems to be that these files are filling up the hard drive.

Comment: Can't you just delete the .dropbox.cache manually if you are running out of space. The cache is cleared every 3 or 4 days automatically anyway.

rm -R ~/Dropbox/.dropbox.cache/*

Comment: @Alex The cache folders which are cleared automatically are called `2019-09-23` etc. The folder I'm describing in the question `temp_dirs` contains the upgrade files. I'm not sure if it's ok just to delete this folder. I'm also surprised the upgrade folder would contain 7.5 GB of upgrade files...

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well. At least in my case, stopping and starting Dropbox daemon from the terminal showed me a message

```
ImportError: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Based on this, I installed the `libatomic1` Ubuntu package. Upon stopping and restarting the Dropbox daemon, the problem was solved. In fact, not only did Dropbox stop filling the `temp_dirs` directory, it removed it altogether.